# Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView not working with error: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: itemView may not be null

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am doing a cross platform project in Xamarin (Android and iOS). I downloaded Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView and I'm getting an error: 
   Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: itemView may not be null

I've tried many ways to do this but a lot of the examples are in MVVM and I haven't converted the project to MVVM yet. I would like CarouselView to work first. I've already tried to different other nuget packages for CarouselView and got really odd errors. This is the closest I've gotten to getting CarouselView to work at all. The other packages wouldn't even compile over some strange compatibility issue. That includes the pre-release's as well (with all three different packages I've tried!).

````
```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Flora.Model;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Flora
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PlantProfilePage : ContentPage
    {
        FloraData floraData = new FloraData();
        public string familyName { get; }
        public string genusName { get; }
        public string scientificName { get; }
        public string taxonid;
        public string indianaFlora { get; set; }
        List<string> uriList { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<FloraData.StringData> uris { get; set; }
        public PlantProfilePage(string familyName, string genusName, string scientificName, string taxonid)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.familyName = familyName;
            this.genusName = genusName;
            this.scientificName = scientificName;
            this.taxonid = taxonid;
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            uriList = new List<string>( await floraData.WebScraper(taxonid));
            FamilyName.BindingContext = this;
            GenusName.BindingContext = this;
            ScientificName.BindingContext = this;
            indianaFlora = uriList.First();
            uriList.Remove(indianaFlora);
            Indiana_Flora_description.BindingContext = this;
            carousel.BindingContext = floraData;
            //PlantPicture.Source = uriList.First();
            int m = 0;
            uris = new ObservableCollection<FloraData.StringData>();
            foreach(var item in uriList)
            {
                if (m < 5)
                {
                    uris.Add(new FloraData.StringData { uri = item });
                    m++;
                }
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Size of uris is " + uris.Count);
            carousel.ItemsSource = uris;
        }//OnAppearing end

    }
}
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Flora.PlantProfilePage"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                <control:CarouselView x:Name="carousel">
                    <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                x:Name="PlantPicture"
                                Source="{Binding uri}"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="150"
                                HeightRequest="150"
                                DownsampleToViewSize="true">
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </control:CarouselView>

                <Label x:Name="FamilyName"
                       Text="{Binding familyName, StringFormat='Family: {0:F0}'}"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold, Italic"/>
                <Label x:Name="GenusName"
                       Text="{Binding genusName, StringFormat='Genus: {0:F0}'}"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold, Italic"/>
                <Label x:Name="ScientificName"
                       Text="{Binding scientificName, StringFormat='Scientific Name: {0:F0}'}"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold, Italic"/>
                <Label x:Name="Indiana_Flora_description"
                       Text="{Binding indianaFlora, StringFormat='Description: {0:F0}'}"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Flora.Model
{
    public class FloraData
    {

        public class StringData
        {
            public string uri { get; set; }
        }
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string[] data;
        public async Task<string[]> GetData()
        {
            string uri = "https://search.idigbio.org/v2/search/records?fields=[%22scientificname%22,%22genus%22,%22family%22,%22taxonid%22]&rq={\"county\":\"floyd\",\"stateprovince\":\"Indiana\",\"kingdom\":\"plantae\"}&no_attribution=true&limit=15";
            Debug.WriteLine("uri string is: " + uri);

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("status 200***IsASuccess!");
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    PlantObject.RootObject dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlantObject.RootObject>(content);
                    Debug.WriteLine("deserialization completed...");
                    data = new string[(dynObj.items.Count * 4)];
                    Debug.WriteLine("itemCount is " + dynObj.items.Count);
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var data1 in dynObj.items)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(i + "foreach loop iteration");
                        Debug.WriteLine("family is: " + data1.indexTerms.family);
                        data[i] = data1.indexTerms.family;
                        Debug.WriteLine("data[i] newest addition is " + data[i]);
                        Debug.WriteLine("genus is: " + data1.indexTerms.genus);
                        data[i + 1] = data1.indexTerms.family + " " + data1.indexTerms.genus;
                        Debug.WriteLine("data[i+1] newest addition is " + data[i + 1]);
                        Debug.WriteLine("scientific name is: " + data1.indexTerms.scientificname);
                        data[i + 2] = data1.indexTerms.scientificname;
                        Debug.WriteLine("data[i+2] newest addition is " + data[i + 2]);
                        Debug.WriteLine("taxonid is " + data1.indexTerms.taxonid);
                        data[i + 3] = data1.indexTerms.taxonid.ToString() + " " + data1.indexTerms.scientificname;
                        Debug.WriteLine("data[i+3] newest addition is " + data[i + 3]);
                        i = i + 4;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving Json data: " + e);
            }
            return data;
        }//GetData end"

        List<string> imageURIs = new List<string>();

        public async Task<List<string>> WebScraper(string taxonid)
        {
            //string uri = "http://midwestherbaria.org/portal/taxa/index.php?taxauthid=1&taxon="+taxonid+"&clid=";
            int i = 0;
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync(@"http://midwestherbaria.org/portal/taxa/index.php?taxauthid=1&taxon=" + taxonid + "&clid=");
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            var uriNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").
                Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("tptnimg"));
            var descriptionNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").
                Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("style", "").Equals("clear:both;"));
            foreach (var node in descriptionNodes)
            {
                if (i < 1)
                {
                    var descr = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(node.InnerText);
                    imageURIs.Add(descr);
                    Debug.WriteLine("newest description is " + imageURIs.Last());
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreach (var node in uriNodes)
            {
                var uri = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(node.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault()?.ChildAttributes("src")
                    .FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
                imageURIs.Add(uri);
                Debug.WriteLine("imageURIs list newest item is " + imageURIs.Last());
            }

            return imageURIs;
        }
        /*
        public async Task<List<string>> GetImage(string scientificName)
        {
            string uri = "https://search.idigbio.org/v2/search/media?fields=[%22accessuri%22]&rq={\"scientificname\":\"" + scientificName + "\"}&no_attribution=true&limit=1";
            Debug.WriteLine("IMAGE: uri string is: " + uri);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("IMAGE: status 200***IsASuccess!");
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    PlantQuery.RootObject dynObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlantQuery.RootObject>(content);
                    Debug.WriteLine("IMAGE: deserialization completed...");
                    //imageURIs = new string[dynObj.itemCount];
                    Debug.WriteLine("IMAGE: itemCount is " + dynObj.itemCount);
                    //int i = 0;
                    foreach (var data1 in dynObj.items)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("IMAGE: foreach loop iteration");
                        Debug.WriteLine("accessURI is: " + data1.indexTerms.accessuri);
                        imageURIs.Add(data1.indexTerms.accessuri);
                        Debug.WriteLine("data[i] newest addition is " + imageURIs.Last());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving Json data: " + e);
            }
            return imageURIs;
        }//GetImage end"
        */

    }//FloraData end
}//namespace end
```
````

I just want the Carousel View to work with around 5 uri images using FFImageLoading for cached images.

**EDIT:**
here's an example of five uri's that would be in one of the example uris ObservableCollection list:

```
https://static.inaturalist.org/photos/504134/medium.jpg?1379628103
https://static.inaturalist.org/photos/8784478/small.jpg?1499006293
https://api.idigbio.org/v2/media/23cbb9eb2750e80848ac95b5d2919323?size=thumbnail
https://api.idigbio.org/v2/media/c085496285be91ace0768eb517cc704b?size=thumbnail
http://swbiodiversity.org/imglib/arizona/IND/IND-0049/IND-0049216_1491615930_tn.jpg
```

Comment: Does the error go away if you comment out `carousel.ItemsSource = uris;`?

Comment: question: Does the error go away if you comment out carousel.ItemsSource = uris;?/////answer: I tried commenting out that segment of code and I got the same error anyway. It's possible I might have to add some more code to the question using "edit".

Comment: @JohnHeinz Hi , Have you solved it ?

Comment: I never solved the problem. I know I tried all kinds of things. I've moved on from that class. I never got help from my team mates. I know never saw of my two team mates code, even though he supposedly worked on it for 50-60 hours over the semester. I busted my behind more than every one and they both got higher grades for trying to cut me out of the project.

Answer (score 0):

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: itemView may not be null

Maybe `Source="{Binding uri}"` and  `carousel.BindingContext = floraData;` can not get the data.From code `BindingContext` of using seems like have some problem,you should check that.Suggest that removing labels control from Xaml first ,and check whether CarouselView can work well.

You also can refer to [this article](https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/) about **CarouselView**.If `FloraData` class like like this:

```
public class FloraData
{
    public class StringData
    {
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    public List<StringData> uris { get; set; }

    public FloraData()
    {
        uris = new List<StringData>() { new StringData() { uri = "https://static.inaturalist.org/photos/504134/medium.jpg?1379628103" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "https://static.inaturalist.org/photos/8784478/small.jpg?1499006293" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "https://api.idigbio.org/v2/media/23cbb9eb2750e80848ac95b5d2919323?size=thumbnail" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "https://api.idigbio.org/v2/media/c085496285be91ace0768eb517cc704b?size=thumbnail" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "http://swbiodiversity.org/imglib/arizona/IND/IND-0049/IND-0049216_1491615930_tn.jpg" }};
    }
}
```

And in ContentPage :

```
FloraData floraData = new FloraData();
carousel.BindingContext = floraData;
```

**Xaml** code as follow:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CarouselView x:Name="carousel" ItemsSource="{Binding uris}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image
                    x:Name="PlantPicture"
                    Source="{Binding uri}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="150"
                    HeightRequest="150">
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

This is easy way to check whether `CarouselView` work well.

> CarouselView : The type initializer for 'Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView' threw an exception

If happen this error, you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.0/4.0.0-pre4) and do as follow:

To get started with Xamarin.Forms 4.0 enable all the new features in your `MainActivity.cs` and `AppDelegate.cs` via the feature flags api:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental", "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```